# Does systemd support time-limited daemon?

Tags: daemon, systemd, time-limiting

I have a daemon which runs for a pre-configured period of time and then quit. User can restart it if needed after that. It seems that systemd cannot handle this type of service. Below is the service file I tried.

```
[Unit]
# DaemonXXX quits
Description=DaemonXXX
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/run/daemonXXX.pid
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/daemonXXX
StandardOutput=journal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I can start service with above unit file. After the daemon quits, I'm also able to start it again by command `systemctrl start DaemonXXX`. But when the service quit after timeout, `systemd` complains that system is degraded because daemonXXX quits. If I add `RemainAfterExit` opton to `[Service]` section,

```
[Unit]
# as above
...

[Service]
# as above
...
RemainAfterExit=yes

...
```

`systemd` will not complain of `degrarded` system but I am no longer able to restart the service again by command `systemctrl start daemonXXX` as `systemd` assumes that `daemonXXX` is running correctly and there is no need to restart it. Is there a way to solve it?